# Word for describing the situation of caring about nothing but one thing

Tags: word-choice

I want to describe a situation in which someone gets interested in something/someone to such extent that he forgets other activities and normal life, and just cares and thinks about the beloved activity/person. This is the sentence in which I want to use this word:

> I devoted myself to this/her/him so *(the word)* that ... .

One word that comes to my mind is to use the adjective form of *ascetic*. But I'm not sure it's the best or even a correct choice.

Comment: Do you want a positive or negative connotation?

Comment: A positive connotation.

Comment: Having a *one-track mind* means what you describe. But it is not a single word.

Comment: I think "obsessive" is the word that most accurately fits the concept, but it tends to have a somewhat (though not completely) negative connotation.

Comment: "Feverishly" might work.  "Zealously" is another candidate.  Or "devotedly" is a possibility (but I see you're already using "devoted").  "Furiously" could convey intensity, but not the devotion you're probably after.  (Thanks to http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/obsessive for the above.)

Comment: How about "intensely"?

Comment: (Or, to come at it from a different angle, "monkishly".)

Comment: Isn't the connotation you're looking for already present in 'devoted'? ISTM you just want an emphatic qualifier like 'utterly' or 'completely'.

Comment: intently , fixedly

Answer (score 4):

That is not what **ascetic** means. I think you mean *obsessively* or *singlemindedly*.

From Merriam-Webster [Ascetic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ascetic):

> 1. practicing strict self-denial as a measure of personal and especially spiritual discipline
> 2. austere in appearance, manner, or attitude

Answer (score 2):

I think *immersed* is the perfect word to describe being "...interested to such an extent that forgets other activities and normal life..."

The definition:

> *verb* 2. involve oneself deeply in a particular activity or interest.

[Source (Google)](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&espv=2&q=define+immersed&oq=define+immersed&gs_l=serp.3..0i20j0l2j0i10j0l4j0i10l2.8792.10499.0.10580.15.11.0.0.0.0.274.1227.0j2j4.6.0.ecynfh...0...1.1.56.serp..9.6.1225.ZkxNOhtA2Lg)

Or maybe, *engrossed*, to a lesser extent.

> *verb* 1. absorb all the attention or interest of.

[Source (Google)](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&espv=2&q=define+engross&oq=define+engross&gs_l=serp.3..0l4j0i30l6.89713.90899.0.91528.8.8.0.0.0.0.180.687.4j2.6.0.ecynfh...0...1.1.56.serp..2.6.686.UyxnYr7kqMY)

Comment: Yeah, "immersed" conveys the meaning and has a mildly positive connotation, but unfortunately there isn't a form that fits the template -- you can't say "immersedly".

Comment: Well, one can, if one wants to get creative and if the context allows for it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *monomania* has the connotation you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

**Obsessively** (can be consisdered negative)
[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obsession):

> the domination of one's thoughts or feelings by a persistent idea, image, desire, etc.

**Single-mindedly** (positive)
[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/single-minded)

> having or showing a single aim or purpose

**Faithfully** (positive)
[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/faithfully?s=t)

> steady in allegiance or affection; loyal; constant

**Unswervingly** (positive)
[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unswervingly)

> 1. Not veering or turning aside
> 2. Constant; steady

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be *addiction*.

Answer (score 0):

Focused.

Also, so focused as to be oblivious to everything else, to the exclusion of everything else.

Another member's suggestion of 'single mindedly' works too.